# Menus do Eclipse sumiram

Tags: eclipse, menu

Atualizei o Eclipse com alguns plugins e todos os menus sumiram, não consigo abrir nada, absolutamente nada!

[image: Menus sumiram]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Poderia pelo menos nos dizer quais plugins, né?

Comment: Eu deixei ele atualizando a noite toda, baixe varios plugins, não sei ao certo qual é!

Comment: A imagem foi capturada de um workspace novo? Se for um workspace existente antes da atualização, tente criar um novo.

Comment: Window > Appearance > Show Toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Limpa todas as configurações do workspace.

1. Sai do eclipse
2. Remove a pasta .metadata
3. Abre novamente o eclipse.

Caso seja uma configuração do seu workspace, será removida. Caso contrario, tente remover os plugins instalados.

Answer (score 0):

Se clicar nesse lugar eles voltam?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MtqDRg7.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Experimente digitar "Perspective" no Quick Access, escolha de preferência o "Java" (Perspective).

Answer (score 0):

No 'Quick Access" você pode digitar "Customize Perspective" e então se abrirá uma janela com algumas abas; numa delas você poderá configurar a visibilidade das 'Tool bars', noutra a visibilidades dos 'Menus'. Estou levando em consideração o meu Eclipse Juno que está em Inglês, ok?